How to get the link/reference of a "Requirement" and "Testrail: Cases" from a JIRA entry via python API?
When using JIRA with TestRail and Confluence you can link a Requirement to a ticket and you can link a TestRail Test Case to a JIRA ticket. For example:

Now using the JIRA python module it is possible to get the ticket details using a code like
from jira import JIRA
myjira = JIRA(server="https://my.jiraserver.com/", basic_auth=(username, password))
issue = jira.issue("PROJ-1")
print(issue.raw)

and print all the details of the ticket. Unfortunately, there is no mention of the linked requirement "DALEX-REQ-001" or the TestRail TestCase "C155535"!
How can I use the JIRA API to get these two fields for the Requirement and the TestRail TestCase?

Can you check what calls is your browser doing? It should be easier that way to at least find some pointers to documentation.

I checked my JIra Administration section on my company's account and there isn't a stock Requirements field which makes me think it is a custom field.  Can you make a python rest apy call to the following JIRA REST API

As it turns out, the references are used in JIRA by a tool/plug-in named "Yogi". There is a reference for these """Yogi""" requirements HERE.
Then you have to guess how to create your query, and the following code does in deed finally return requirements information associated with a ticket:
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Username and Password
username = "your_username"
password = "your_password"

# Headers
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Complete JIRA URL
jira_url = "https://my.jira-instance.com/rest/reqs/1/issuelinks/TEST-2619"

# Make the GET request to fetch issue details
response = requests.get(
    jira_url,
    headers=headers,
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
)
print(response.json())


To fetch data based on requirement & testRail, You can write something like this:
from jira import JIRA

myjira = JIRA(server="https://my.jiraserver.com/", basic_auth=("username", "password"))

issue = myjira.issue("PROJ-1")

print(issue.raw)

for link in issue.fields.issuelinks:
    if hasattr(link, 'outwardIssue'):
        print(f"Outward issue: {link.outwardIssue.key}")
    if hasattr(link, 'inwardIssue'):
        print(f"Inward issue: {link.inwardIssue.key}")

For testRails:
test_case = issue.fields.{customfield_12345} // add yours  


Sorry, but that does not seem to work at all. I get no link-related output whatsoever.

You can fetch data by making an API call
Sample Code Snippet:
from jira import JIRA
import requests


jira = JIRA(server="https://my.jiraserver.com/", basic_auth=("username", "password"))
issue = jira.issue("PROJ-1")

# fetch fields
requirement_field = issue.fields.your_field_id
testrail_field = issue.fields.your_field_id

# TestRail API call
testrail_url = "https://my.testrailserver.com/"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
auth = ("testrail_username", "testrail_api_key")

# fetch linked test cases
response = requests.get(
    f"{testrail_url}/index.php?/api/v2/get_cases",
    headers=headers,
    auth=auth,
)
print(response.json())


I checked the Jira Administration section on a sample account and there isn't a stock Requirements field which makes me think it is a custom field in your cloud installation (unless your are using a server installation).
Can you clarify if you are using cloud or server impleentation?  I can't tell from the url you specified if it is a hosted jira server implementation or a custom url for a cloud implementation.
If it is a cloud implementation, can you make a python rest api GET call to the following JIRA REST V3 API named field
 https://sample_company.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/field

Make sure to update the url with your cloud instance or it will fail as sample_company isn't a real domain.
That will return all the fields whether they are system or custom in json format.  You can then parse the json to find the field(s) once you know the field names.  Here is the structure of a sample field from a sample jira cloud installation for reference
{
  "id": "customfield_10072",
  "key": "customfield_10072",
  "name": "samplefield",
  "custom": false,
  "orderable": true,
  "navigable": true,
  "searchable": true,
  "clauseNames": [
    "cf[10072]"
  ],
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "system": "samplefield"
  },
  "customId":10072
},

The name will most likely be Requirements for the custom field you are lookiing for since that is what is rendering in the screenshot but id and key for the field will have a name such as customfield_NNNNN where the NNNNN is a custom number depending on how many custom fields you have in your installation.  Once you know this id or key, you can make a python rest api call to the JIRA REST V3 API for your issue and get the custom field values from the previous API.  This will change from customer install to customer install so I can't give the exact field.
Here is the Jira Rest API for an issue for example:
 https://sample_company.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/jira_ticket

where jira_ticket is the name of the jira_ticket you are trying to get the data from.
So for example if my ticket is XX-13515, I would make a GET Request to
 https://sample_company.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/XX-13515

That would return JSON output.  You could then parse the results for the customfield_NNNN for your Requirements field and the other field you are looking for.  There could be multiple ways you would find the field in the results for your issue such as:
      {
        "id": "customfield_10027",
        "key": "customfield_10027",
        "name": "Requirements",
        "untranslatedName": "Requirements",
        "custom": true,
        "orderable": true,
        "navigable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "clauseNames": [
          "cf[10027]",
          "Requirements",
          "Requirements[Paragraph]"
        ],
        "schema": {
          "type": "string",
          "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:textarea",
          "customId": 10027
        }
      },

or it could be a simple url such as
 "customfield_10072": null,  

or possibly some other type.  So anything would else be speculation at this point without some sample results from you to investigate further.
